# Creating an HTML dropdown array in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to create an html dropdown with all the names in a txt file. I make an AJAX call to a PHP file that reads every line in the text file. It works fine when I create a string like this:

```
<?php
...
$repDropdown = '';
while(!feof($file))
  {
  $rep = fgets($file);
  $repDropdown .= '<option value="' . $rep . '">' . $rep . '</option>';
  }
...
echo $repDropdown;
?>
```

However, when I create an array (which I need to do for various reasons), it fails, I believe since it uses HTML characters. I'm not sure how to fix this though.

```
<?php
$reps = array();
$repDropdown = '<option value=""></option>'; //array();
while(!feof($file))
  {
  $rep = fgets($file);
  $repDropdown .= '<option value="' . $rep . '">' . $rep . '</option>';
  }
  $reps[0] = $repDropdown;
  echo json_encode($reps)
?>
```

Comment: I bet you didn't modify your JavaScript code. Show us JS function.

Comment: You left a semicolon off echo json_encode($reps)

Comment: `$reps[0] = $repDropdown;` should be `$reps[] = $repDropdown;` as it is your forever replacing the first item of the array

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use

$array = "1" , "2" , "3";

```
foreach($array->item as $reps){
echo '
<option value="' . $reps . '">' . $reps . '</option>';
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop, you need use trim($rep) to get rid of the newline.  You also need to use htmlentities($repDropdown) before inserting it into the array.  Then to retrieve it from the array, you have to reverse the htmlentities() with html_entity_decode($reps[0]).

Try this code:

```
<?php
$reps = array();
$repDropdown = '<select>';

$fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
while ( $current_line = fgets($fp) ) {
  // do stuff to the current line here
  $current_line = trim($current_line);
  $repDropdown .= '<option value="' . $current_line . '">' . $current_line . '</option>';
}
$repDropdown .= '</select>';
fclose($fp);

$repDropdown = htmlentities($repDropdown);
$reps[] = $repDropdown;
echo json_encode($reps) . '<br />';
echo html_entity_decode($reps[0]);
?>
```

**Documentation:**
http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php
https://www.php.net/html_entity_decode